# Why do I only get 3840x1080 with my mac and samsung g9 neo monitor?

Tags: mac, display

The monitor is rated for a max resolution of 5120x1440, yet my iMac only shows a maximum resolution of 3840x1080 available.

I use a usb-c to displayport cable to connect the iMac with the monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out myself. The issue is displayport version:

- If you use displayport v1.1 and v1.4,  you will get 3880 x 1080
- If you use displayport v1.2, you will get 5120 x 1440

To change, use the configuration options on the display

- click the button at the bottom of g9 neo, select menu,
- select system
- select displayport version
- select 1.2

On mac, you will get 5120 x 1440 ! like me

[image]

PS: If the display isn't recognized after a reboot:

- power off g9 first. reconnect g9 with mac.
- then restart mac, then power on g9.
- I had to try 3 times, until g9 have signal.